# Como hago para que mi programa acumule las respuestas y cuando ponga un carácter determinado muestre el resultado acumulado?

Tags: c, bucle-for

Hice un un programa que suma, resta, multiplica y divida programa se mantenga realizando operaciones acumulativas mientras el usuario ingrese alguna de las letras que corresponden a una operación,

el resultado final debería mostrar únicamente si el usuario ingresa la letra X. digamos que después de 2 restas y 3 divisiones aparezca el resultado de todas las sumas y restas como un único resultado, como se haría para para que el programa haga esto?

Aqui dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char salir_continuar, caracter;

    do
    {
          printf("\n s) Suma");
          printf("\n r) Resta");
          printf("\n m) Multiplicacion");
          printf("\n d) Division");
          printf("\n\nElija una opcion: ");
          scanf("%c", &caracter);

  switch(caracter){

     case ('s'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
             scanf("%d", &a);
             printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
             scanf("%d", &b);

             printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",a+b);
             break;


     case ('r'): printf ("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                  scanf("%d", &a);
                 printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                  scanf("%d", &b);

                  printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d", a-b);
                  break;



    case ('m'):   printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);

            printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",a*b);
            break;



    case ('d'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);

            printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",  a/b);
            break;


    default: ;

}

     printf("\n\n quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...");
     printf("\n\n elija n para salir o s para continuar: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c", &salir_continuar);

    system("cls");

    }while(salir_continuar!='n');

   printf("\n Hasta luego");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Deberias ir guardando el resultado de las cuentas no? eso es lo que preguntas?

Comment: Exacto, como haría para guardarlas y mostrarlas al final cuando presiono un carácter determinado

Comment: igual que como guardas todas las otras que estan en tu codigo??? no entiendo tu problema.. estas guardando variables por todos lados...

Comment: Creo que no formule bien la pregunta, lo que pregunto es como hacer que programa se mantendrá 
realizando operaciones acumulativas mientras el usuario ingrese alguna de las letras que corresponden a una operación, 
el resultado final debe mostrar únicamente si el usuario ingresa una letra digamos x

Comment: La respuesta sigue siendo la misma, anda guardando el valor en alguna variable que acumule el resultado... todo lo que pedis ya lo hace tu codigo.. solo que en lugar de mostrar el resultado, lo guardas en una variable...

Comment: Ya veo y que tendría que hacer para mostrar el acumulado?, quiero decir sacarlo de donde esta guardarlo? pedir la variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podés hacer es crear una nueva variable llamada 'acumulado', y cuando realices una operación, además de solo mostrarla por pantalla, vas acumulando esos resultados en la variable, por ejemplo

```
case ('s'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
             scanf("%d", &a);
             printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
             scanf("%d", &b);
             
             acumulado = acumulado+a+b
             printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",acumulado);
             break;
```

Y eso mismo con el resto de las operaciones.
Para mostrar el resultado, podés agregar un case('x') que muestre la variable 'acumulado'.

Comment: Estaba pensando eso mismo y me terminaste de confirmar. me has dado una buena idea, muchas gracias